# PERMANOVA - unbalanced design

Tags: r, vegan, multivariate-testing

I am new to statistical analysis and R. I have data of relative abundance (in percentage) of 5 taxa in 8 ponds. The number of samples in the 8 ponds ranges from 7 to 12 (making the design unbalanced). Can I use PERMANOVA (`vegan::adonis2`) and PERMDISP to test if the composition of the 5 taxa is different in the 8 ponds?

Thank you!

I have tried as follows:

```
matrix<-as.matrix(Data[,c(5:9)]) # columns 5:9 refers to relative abundance of the 5 taxa in percentage

dist<-vegdist(matrix, method="robust.aitchison", na.rm = F)

adonis2(dist~ Pond, data=Data)

anova(betadisper(dist,Data$Pond))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2APx7.png)

Does the result mean that there are no difference between the ponds as a whole? And how can I analyse the differences of individual taxon among the ponds?

Thank you!

Comment: FYI; you don't need to take a screen shot of your output from the R console. It's just text, so copy it to the clipboard and then paste it into your question and wrap it in backticks to indicate it is code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's fine. But you don't want the `anova()` method for `betadisper()` objects; you should use `permutest()` on the `betadisper()` object to get the permutation test of heterogeneous dispersions.

The results of the PERMANOVA mean you fail to reject the null hypothesis that the variation explained by `Pond` is consistent with the Null hypothesis of **no effect**. The results do not indicate there is no difference between ponds; there are differences (otherwise the `SumOfSqs` would be 0), but they are just small.

Analysing the per taxon differences would just be a univariate model so not really something you would do with `adonis2()`...

Comment: Thank you!! Would you please also recommend any ways of doing the univariate tests (with such relative abundance data and unbalanced data)?

Comment: And do you know if 'pairwise.adonis2' can be used with such unbalanced data? Thanks a lot!

Comment: As far as I understand what `pairwise.adonis2()` does, it should be fine for unbalanced data (though your power to detect a true effect will obviously change). Univariate tests would be via generalized linear models on the abundances for example.